# Select multiple column with join and keep the same name as in the select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a SQL Request and I want to know if I can keep the same name as the name that I use in my select

Exemple :

```
SELECT users.id, users.block, users.login, users.address
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_info ON users.id = users_info.id
```

I want to get the column like

```
users.id | users.block | users.login | users.address
```

But I got it like that

```
id | block | login | address
```

And I want to know if there is another way as to do it with alias

```
SELECT users.id as users.id , users.block as users.block , users.login as users.login , users.address as users.address
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_info ON users.id = users_info.id
```

I'm working with pdo on php, someone know a function that can send the table name with the field when i fetchAll ?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried and what results do you see?

Comment: Well you could use explicit aliases, I suppose ... As for the second question, no idea what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: I tried but i get it without the table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the name between backticks or single quotes

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/HULSG80471)**

For example:

```
select version() as `mysql.version`

select version() as 'mysql.version'
```

Comment: Thank's but I want to know if there is another way as an alias

Comment: @Alexandre Corvino.  That's what Juan just showed you ``mysql.version`` is the alias for version().

Comment: @JuveLeo1906 But I don't want to use an alias x( ! I want to know an another way.....

Comment: @Alexandre Corvino.  Ah, sorry misinterpreted your question...one way would be to create your column names with the table prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I will use **fetch** instead of **fetchAll** and **PDOStatement::getColumnMeta(nbFetch)["table"]** in each fetch then copy it in another array !

Thanks for help !